# Adding a linear layer to an existing model on Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to add a new layer to an existing network (as the first layer) and train it on the original input. When I add a convolutional layer everything works perfectly but when I change it to linear it doesn't seem to train. Any ideas why?
Here is the whole network:

```
class ActorCritic(torch.nn.Module): #original model
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, action_space):
        super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(num_inputs, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTMCell(32 * 3 * 3, 256)

        num_outputs = action_space.n
        self.critic_linear = nn.Linear(256, 1)
        self.actor_linear = nn.Linear(256, num_outputs)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs, (hx, cx) = inputs
        x = F.elu(self.conv1(inputs))
        x = F.elu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.elu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.elu(self.conv4(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 32 * 3 * 3)
        hx, cx = self.lstm(x, (hx, cx))
        x = hx
        return self.critic_linear(x), self.actor_linear(x), (hx, cx)

class TLModel(torch.nn.Module): #new model
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model, num_inputs):
        super(TLModel, self).__init__()
        self.new_layer = nn.Linear(1*1*42*42, 1*1*42*42)
        self.pretrained_model = pretrained_model

    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs, (hx, cx) = inputs
        x = F.elu(self.new_layer(inputs.view(-1, 1*1*42*42)))
        return self.pretrained_model((x.view(1,1,42,42), (hx, cx)))
```

I tried different activation functions (not just elu). it works with conv:

```
 class TLModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model, num_inputs):
        super(TLModel, self).__init__()
        self.new_layer = nn.Conv2d(num_inputs, num_inputs, 1)
        self.pretrained_model = pretrained_model

    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs, (hx, cx) = inputs
        x = F.elu(self.new_layer(inputs))
        return self.pretrained_model((x, (hx, cx)))
```

The number of inputs is 1 and the size of an input is 1x1x42x42

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you had supplied the error message. From what you have written, I can only guess that you have forgotten to squeeze your input. You write your input is of size `1x1x42x42`, i.e. it is 4-dimensional. `nn.Conv2D` expects a 4-dimensional input. `nn.Linear` instead expects a 2-dimensional input.

Therefore, try to call `input = input.squeeze()` before feeding it to your model. This removes singleton dimensions, and hence will make your input 2-dimensional as there are two singleton dimensions.

As a side note, `nn.Linear` expects input of dimension  `batch_size x feat_dim`. Does a linear layer really make sense on your data?
As another side note, when people usually add layers to networks they put them in the end not the beginning, but I trust you have good reasons to do so and know what you're doing :)

Good Luck!

Comment: I actually don't get any error message, it just doesn't seem to train with linear (but does with conv).

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions shouldn't be a problem since you are changing the view in the forward function. I believe adding the FCN in the starting of the network doesn't really make much difference, you can check by removing the layer and retraining the network, it would produce similar results.

Try to imagine it as if you are trying to detect features of a cat (whiskers, ears etc,) you don't really need information from all the pixels in the image but only neighboring pixels, so a fully connected layer just complicates the network.

Comment: I have a reason for adding a fcn but first I wanted to check a basic example just to see if it worked. I managed to initialize the weights as the identity matrix so now it works at the first time it runs. I think that the activation is also influencing the process because it works in the first time only with certain functions (like tanh or none).